# EditText: how to display the number while you are typing it?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have three EditText widgets in my app and the XML for one of them is below.  They work, mostly, but the problem is that the actual widget is at the bottom of my devices screen.  When I tap the widget, and the numeric keypad is displayed, it completely covers the text entry window and I can't see what number I'm typing.  Can I modify TextView so that when the Keypad is displayed on my device, it also displays the number that I'm currently typing?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditTextPrices"            android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:singleLine="true"                   android.imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

Another problem is that when I finish typing one number, instead of returning me to the main activity screen, it brings up the numeric keypad for the next TextEdit widget.  I don't want this to happen.  I had thought that setting android.imeOptions="actionDone" would cause the keypad to go away and be done when I finished typing the number, but not so.  How can I stop the 'next' window from appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into adding [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) to your manifest file. "adjustPan" as it's value is probably what you want though I've found that it sometimes fails to account for the space taken just above a softkeyboard by the strip of word-guesses while you're typing things in.

Comment: When you say manifest file, do you mean AndroidManifest.xml.  If so, where do I put android:windowSoftInputMode?

Comment: Yes, the in AndroidManifest.xml.
Have another look at the link, it's an attribute of the xml element for your activity.
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" . . . >

Comment: Okay.  That worked.  And furthermore, it somehow solved the other problem I had with 'Next'.  Thanks!

Comment: Most likely.  My device did not get an ICS update and being a soft-keyboard from gingerbread era it probably just doesn't work right.  Whatever notifies the activity to adjustPan as we want in this case is getting called right after my keyboard draws but before the word strip as it appears a split second later.

Answer (score 1):

Add  android:windowSoftInputMode=”adjustPan” to your manifest for the activity.  That will cause the activity to scroll up so that the focused edit text is always on screen.

Answer (score 1):

The other advice given to use adjustPan is good, and another idea is to put your layout in a scroll view.

Regarding your second problem, how are you handling actionDone?

For example this is how I hide the keyboard (or do whatever you want when they press done).

```
final EditText editTextPrices = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPrices);
editTextPrices.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionID, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionID == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) MyClass.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(bugemailaddress.getWindowToken(), 0);
            // DO OTHER HANDLING OF INPUT HERE
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
 });
```

Comment: ScrollView might be problematic for me because I also have ListViews in this app and I', told the two don't go well together.  Regarding the second problems, the above answers somehow solved it.  Thanks.